# Magento loop through pages

Tags: magento, loops

I found enough documenatation about how to loop through all available categories in Magento, only the thing i want is to loop trough available pages in Magento to include them in my global navigation.

So im asking you guys, someone knows how to do this? I imagine myself it should look something like this

```
foreach ($this->getPages() as $page) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$page->getUrl().'">'.$page->getName().'</a></li>';
}
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - [Magento static pages menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226853/magento-static-pages-menu)

And this - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/12462/