# Magento CMS pages menu

Tags: php, magento, menu

I have modified the code from [Magento static pages menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226853/magento-static-pages-menu) a little bit to include a class for the active menu link.

```
<div>
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());?>
<?php  $collection->getSelect()
      ->where('is_active = 1'); ?>
<ul id="nav-top-list">
<?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
  <?php $PageData = $page->getData(); ?>
  <?php if($PageData['menu']!= 'false') { ?>
  <li>
    <a href="/<?php echo $PageData['identifier']?>"<?php if ($url == "/".$PageData['identifier']) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><?php echo $PageData['title'] ?></a>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I have added a new field to the CMS pages to specify if the page should be included in the menu by using true or false. Actually, as you can see above I am only checking for a setting of false, everything else will get a link. You'll need to add a new field to the cms_page table if you are going to use this.

```
        $fieldset->addField('menu', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'menu',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('On Menu'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('On Menu'),
        'required'  => true,
        'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
    ));
```

I have also added another field to the CMS pages named sortorder which contains a number for the order the links should be on the menu. Has anybody got any tips on how I could use the new sortorder field to sort the order of the menu links?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@Andy Flan

the ('sortorder') triggers a sql error.

Works better with

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(
    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->setOrder('**sort_order**', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like?:

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(
    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->setOrder('sortorder', 'asc');
```